# Multiple choice quiz with unity and a firebase web api

Tags: c#, json, firebase, unity-game-engine, json-deserialization

Currently working on a project that requires making a quiz game in unity with data coming from a firebase web api

I was able to retreive data an put them in text fields and buttons in the scene but i couldn't figure out a way to make the logic of the game, how to identify the correct answer and add score.

This is my answer code

```
    public void Answer()
{
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
        Debug.Log("Correct Answer");
        theQuiz.correct();
    }
    else
    {
        GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
        Debug.Log("Wrong Answer");
        theQuiz.wrong();
    }
}
```

And this is my correct answer verification code

```
            var quest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionResponse>(response.downloadHandler.text);
        if (quest.documents.Count >= 0)
        {
            currentQuestion = Random.Range(0, quest.documents.Count);
            QuestionTxt.text = quest.documents[currentQuestion].fields.q.stringValue;
            Ch1Txt.text = quest.documents[currentQuestion].fields.ch1.stringValue;
            Ch2Txt.text = quest.documents[currentQuestion].fields.ch2.stringValue;
            Ch3Txt.text = quest.documents[currentQuestion].fields.ch3.stringValue;
            Ch4Txt.text = quest.documents[currentQuestion].fields.ch4.stringValue;

             Text c1 = Ch1Txt.GetComponent<Text>();

            totalQuestions = quest.documents.Count;

            c1.GetComponent<AnswerScriptApi>().isCorrect = true;
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok just done it